# ambiguous use of subscript swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

К сожалению не совсем разобрался со свифтом, помогите пожалуйста исправить

```
  do {
        let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let allContacts: AnyObject! = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        if let arrJSON = allContacts {
            for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {

                let aObject = arrJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]


                names.append(aObject["post_name"] as! String)
                contacts.append(aObject["post_inn"] as! String)
                //contacts.append(aObject["email"] as! String)
                let post=Post(post_id: aObject["post_id"] as! String,post_name: aObject["post_name"] as! String,post_inn: aObject["post_inn"] as! String)
                posts.append(post)
            }
        }
        print(names)
        print(contacts)
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
     for index in 0...allContacts.count-1 {

            if let channels = allContacts as? [[String:AnyObject]], !channels.isEmpty {
                let channel = channels[index] // now the compiler knows it's [String:AnyObject]
                names.append(channel["doc_fio"] as! String)
                contacts.append(channel["specialisation_name"] as! String)
                photos.append(channel["doc_photo"] as! String

            }

        }
```